# Can't able to install p12 file on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, security-framework

I'm getting a p12 file from server. I need to install that p12 file in device profiles, which is in settings app.
Below is my code

```
var documentsDirectory: NSURL?
var fileURL: NSURL?

documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last! as NSURL
fileURL = documentsDirectory!.appendingPathComponent("AuthRsa.p12")! as NSURL

if (fileURL!.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil)) {
     print("file exist")
}else{
     print("file doesn't exist")
     do {
             try p12FileData.write(to: fileURL! as URL)
        } catch {
             print(error)
        }
}
print(fileURL!)
let p12Data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileURL!.path!)!
let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
let options : NSDictionary = [key : "test"]

var rawItems : CFArray?

let securityError: OSStatus = SecPKCS12Import(p12Data, options, &rawItems)
print(securityError)

let items = rawItems! as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
let firstItem = items[0]
let identity = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentity?
let trust = firstItem[kSecImportItemTrust as String] as! SecTrust?

let ptr = p12Data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)

let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, ptr, p12Data.length)
let cert:SecCertificate? = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfData!)
print(cert!)
let addquery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate, kSecValueRef as String: certificate!, kSecAttrLabel as String: "My Certificate"]         
let status = SecItemAdd(addquery as CFDictionary, nil)
print(status)
```

I'm getting crash "Unexpectedly found nil value" at the line print(cert!), because certificate is not able to generating.

So can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.